# My main username is not in the sudoers file

Tags: boot, dual-boot, sudo

I was trying to install some software/edit files with my main username(not `root`)
But I got this error `[X] is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.`
I tried to edit the `/etc/sudoers` file by using `sudo` and `su username` but I got the same error!

How I'm supposed to add my  username to`sudoers` file while I cant access it anyway?
I also tried to follow this guide [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/fixsudo).

is the guide says, when booting 2 Operating systems(that's my case), then selecting Ubuntu, a menu will let you choose to start normally/open recovery mode/etc, but it's not happening for me, even if I hold `shift` no menu will pop up.

I installed Ubuntu by using Wubi and my Ubuntu version:12.04 LTS.

Comment: That guide looks pretty good for dealing with your sudo problem, and would probably work if you could follow it. I think you need to change your question to be "How can I boot into recovery mode?" and then ask about sudo if following that guide does not fix the problem.

Comment: To boot into recovery mode, restart the PC and hold down the Shift button, then follow the instructions - http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/fixsudo

Comment: you will not get the Grub menu for a wubi install. If you have any other user account you can access, which has permissions to edit sudoers file, that may help. Else, you may have to use external tools for that. It certainly can be solved. :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Open a **Root Terminal** and type `visudo` (to access and edit the list).

Navigate to the bottom of the `sudoers` file that is now displayed in the terminal.

Just under the line that looks like the following:

```
    root ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Add the following (replacing `user` with your actual username):

```
    user ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Now save the file. The procedure for this will depend on your editor:

- `nano` – <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to exit
- `vim` – <kbd>`:wq`</kbd>

Comment: His problem is in accessing a root terminal. And, you assumed that his editor is `nano`. Kindly improve it.

Comment: How can he open a Root Terminal without giving root password which is not working?

Comment: You can easily find some online tutorial to retrieve/change your root password and you'll be able to open a standard terminal and give `su` to become root. Otherwise, you may want to boot with a Live CD and access the file after having mounted the HD. Finally, I wasn't referring to `nano`. `visudo` is included in standard Ubuntu installation.

Comment: `Ctrl + K` then  `X` worked.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way to add an user to `sudoers` file is run the command bellow as user with permission to execute `gpasswd`:

```
sudo gpasswd -a username sudo
```

Comment: Many thanks @monteirobrena. Your tip is very useful :)))

Answer (score 4):

the process described at search: "[psychocats](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/fixsudo) ubuntu fixsudo" helped me on Lubuntu 13.04

Enter recovery mode then

```
mount -o rw,remount /

adduser username sudo
```

Comment: This is the easiest way I've encountered to solve this problem. For anyone wondering, you need to boot in recovery mode and choose "Drop to root shell prompt" to execute these commands (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the root password (may have been configured during installation), you can open a terminal and type `su -l`, then the root password. Lastly follow jasmines answer. To start edit in vim, go to the line below `root ALL=(ALL) ALL` and press `i`. I was able to follow these steps to add my account after an initial Fedora install.