# What is the right way to gain sudo privileges

Tags: sudo, adduser

I have just created a new Rackspace cloud server and I need to set it up.

I created a new user with the `adduser` command and currently the user is only in a group with the same name. For the sudo privileges what should I do:

- use `visudo` to edit `/etc/sudoers` file [→](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151200/my-main-username-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file)
- add the user to the sudo group [→](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168280/how-do-i-grant-sudo-privileges-to-an-existing-user)
- create a new `admin` group, add it to sudoers, and then add the user to this group [→](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line)

I can not decide what's the right way to do this. Why should I choose one over other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to edit the sudoers file.
Creating a new admin group is redundant.
Adding the user to the sudo group is the best idea. See here:
[How do I grant sudo privileges to an existing user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168280/how-do-i-grant-sudo-privileges-to-an-existing-user?rq=1)