# How can I update my boost version when I am not allowed to sudo?

Tags: python, boost

I am a newbie for both Python and this website and I would like to obtain your assistance for this problem

I am on a Project where I have to log-into a remote cluster for batch process.

I have been confronted by this problem for 1 week by now, have been searching for possible solutions here and AskUbuntu, but none of them worked.

---

I am trying to configure $HOME/external/LHAPDF-6.1.6

Code

```
ssh -XY trentacoollime@starbucks.com

cd external/LHAPDF-6.1.6


./configure --prefix=$HOME/external
```

Terminal

> checking for Cython >= 0.19... no
>
> checking if the g++ compiler accepts the -pedantic flag... yes
>
> checking if the g++ compiler accepts the -Wall flag... yes
>
> checking if the g++ compiler accepts the -Wno-long-long flag... yes
>
> checking if the g++ compiler accepts the -Qunused-arguments flag... no
>
> checking for Boost headers version >= 1.41.0... no
>
> configure: error: cannot find Boost headers version >= 1.41.0

In order to solve problem

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

However, when I attempt to execute the code,

> trentacoollime is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

In order to make myself as sudoer, I almost tried all methods given in this website, but none of them worked.

**A SHORT** list of my referrals include these links

https://www.tecmint.com/fix-user-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file-the-incident-will-be-reported-ubuntu/

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179954/username-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file-this-incident-will-be-reported

[How do I add myself into the sudoers group?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124166/how-do-i-add-myself-into-the-sudoers-group)

[My main username is not in the sudoers file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151200/my-main-username-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file)

---

**Please note that, when I am in my own machine (outside of the cluster), it gave me the same terminal error of**

> configure: error: cannot find Boost headers version >= 1.41.0

for the first attempt. However, when I tried

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

it made me to successfully configure the LHAPDF-6.1.6

---

Thus, I believe the sudo libboost install code is the good answer, but I would like to find out how to implement in my cluster environment.

Given that my advisor told me in this cluster, it would never work anyway and I should not try to do so, I concluded finding a new method to add myself as a sudoer is **not an option**

Thus, for my neophyte idea of possible answers are

- I wonder if there is any good method with linking the boost version, that exists in my own machine from installation to the my trentacoollime remote cluster account
- I have these (and some others that also have title of libboost)
  (my home directory is /storage/5/home)

  /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem-mt.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_program_options-mt.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_program_options.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_system-mt.so.5
  /usr/lib64/libboost_system.so.5

Can I exploit any out of these library guys?

- Your any other ingenious idea!

I really appreciate your help

I would love to break this thing and hope for a simple explanation that I could learn.

Thanks so much.

Comment: First check if you can go without BOOST as the latest version of LHAPDF does not depend on it! If it is not possible - why not simply ask your cluster sysadmin to  install the needed software for you? This is probably a scientific cluster and it is normal to ask for special libraries!  You can install boost in your cluster home folder and link the compilation to there... but since your asking this question - try first the easier steps.

Comment: Try setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` per https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168340/where-is-ld-library-path-how-do-i-set-the-ld-library-path-env-variable or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux